# View rows of tuple with specific value

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have rows of data containing tuples of words. I want to see rows that contain a specific word: "accord". Here is an example of my data

| id | stemming |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [yes, no, maybe] |
| 2 | [accord, yes] |
| 3 | [accord] |
| 4 | [maybe, do, accord, not] |
| 5 | [never, maybe, yes] |

Here's what I expect the new dataframe to look like:

| id | stemming |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | [accord, yes] |
| 3 | [accord] |
| 4 | [maybe, do, accord, not] |

I tried this code but it says `unhashable type: 'Int64Index'`

```
s = data['stemming'].explode().isin(['accord'])
data_new = data.loc(s.index[s])
data_new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = data['stemming'].apply(lambda x: 'accord' in x)
data[s]
```